# Building application using cordova and xcode9

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a problem, while building my cordova application.
I am receiving an error:

> error: exportArchive: "myAppName.app" requires a provisioning profile
>   with the Push Notifications feature.

As I read over the internet, there was a bug, until ios-platform 4.5.2 (exclusive).

Since v4.5.2 the bug was fixed.

I have v4.5.4 installed, so I shouldn't receive such error, but I am.

How to fix this issue?

In my opinion - I have to create a provisioning profile in Apple Center website using APNs sertificate - but I don't have such option there. I can create provisioning profiles using only App Development or App Distribution certificates. There is no option to select APNs certificates.

I'm stuck.